PHP DOMElement nodeValue not persisting escaped(encoded) characters
I have been given an unusual goal and that is to create an XML with no CDATA element from a multidimensional array with these constraints:

CDATA shouldn't be used
<, >, ', ", & - These chars should be encoded.

But when I'm setting the nodeValue after converting ' and " to &apos; and &quot;, the value is not being retained in the XML node and are being unescaped.
 private function convertElement(DOMElement $element, $value)
    {...
   $value = htmlspecialchars($value ?? '', ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES); 
   $element->nodeValue = $value;

Node element is not retaining the encoded char value, and &apos and &quotes are decoded to ' and "
dd($element->nodeValue);
// &lt;p itemprop='description'&gt;&#039;Test single quotes'&lt;/p&gt;itemprop="description">
// Should have retained
// &lt;p itemprop=&quot;description&quot;&gt;&#039;Test single quotes&#039;&lt;/p&gt;

And if i use appendChild(), it is causing the values to double escape.
//value = Test Ampersand &
 $textNode = $this->document->createTextNode($value);  
 $element->appendChild($textNode); 

//Test Amersand &amp;amp;

My issue seems to be related to this phenomenon DOMElement nodeValue inconsistant get vs set
I'll appreciate any workaround or suggestions.
Thanks!

Please show minimal but complete samples of input and output. If you have a CDATA section child node as the only child node in an element and you want to replace the CDATA section by a text node then just do that, use element->replaceChild(doc->createTextNode(element->firstChild->value), element->firstChild). The serializer will take care automatically of escaping any characters if you serialize/save the DOM tree.

There is no need to escape quotes in text nodes. And what's wrong with CDATA?

@MartinHonnen I have updated the question, it can be reduced to, how can i create an XML with ' and &quotes; not being unescaped.

Hi @Olivier I'm total aware about that and that's why I wrote unusual goal, the backend team will parse this XML for further processing and that's the constraint they gave.

"that's the constraint they gave" That constraint makes no sense. Any XML parser can read a literal (unescaped) quote.

Please try this
function convertElement(DOMElement $element, $value) {
    $encodedValue = htmlspecialchars($value ?? '', ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES);
    $textNode = $element->ownerDocument->createTextNode($encodedValue);
    while ($element->hasChildNodes()) {
        $element->removeChild($element->firstChild);
    }
    $element->appendChild($textNode);
    echo $element->ownerDocument->saveXML($element);
}
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root><element><![CDATA[<p itemprop="description">\'Test single quotes\'</p>]]></element></root>');

$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('element')->item(0);
$cdataContent = $element->nodeValue;
convertElement($element, $cdataContent);
echo $doc->saveXML();


CDATASection nodes handle encodings differently, so it is understandable to avoid them. They are mostly for BC and human readability.
Quotes are only needed to be escaped inside an attribute using them. The DOM serializer avoids unnecessary escaping. So you only option would be the write your own serializer.
The nodeValue property implementation in PHP does not match the DOM standard and is imho broken. It will only partially escape input.
The original DOM standard required you to create and add a text node. Current DOM (and PHP) has the textContent property.
Here is an example:
$data = "\n, <, >, ', \n, \", &";

$document = new DOMDocument();
$root = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('foo'));

// create an child element with a textnode child
$root
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('bar'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($data));
  
// add an child element and set textContent
$root
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('bar'))
  ->textContent = $data;
  
$root
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('bar'))
  ->setAttribute('a', $data);
  
$document->formatOutput = true;
echo $document->saveXML();

Output:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar>
, &lt;, &gt;, ', 
, ", &amp;</bar>
  <bar>
, &lt;, &gt;, ', 
, ", &amp;</bar>
  <bar a="&#10;, &lt;, &gt;, ', &#10;, &quot;, &amp;"/>
</foo>

